# QUERY: where has_many association does not contain specific value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models `Invoice` and `InvoiceEvent`

`Invoice` has many `InvoiceEvents`

`InvoiceEvent` has a field `state`

I'd like to write a query to find all `Invoices` that DOES NOT have an `InvoiceEvent` with the `state = 'paid'`

My first attempt was

```
Invoice.joins(:events).where("invoice_events.state != 'paid'")
```

But this simply grabbed all Invoices since a paid invoice will still have other events leading up to the paid event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you want all the `InvoiceEvent`s that *do* have a state of `'paid'`:

```
InvoiceEvent.where(:state => 'paid')
```

From there you can get the `Invoice`s that have events with such a state:

```
InvoiceEvent.where(:state => 'paid').select(:invoice_id)
```

Then you can use a subquery to find all the `Invoice`s that aren't in that list:

```
Invoice.where.not(
  :id => InvoiceEvent.where(:state => 'paid').select(:invoice_id)
)
```

Note the `select(:invoice_id)` call. ActiveRecord will convert that to a subquery like:

```
where id not in (select invoice_id from ...)
```

so that database will be doing the work without having to pull a bunch of data in Rails-land only to send it back to the database.

Comment: Ok i was thinking something like this but thought it might be more expensive than a query that can do it all

Comment: That is one query that can do it all.

Comment: Using `select` instead of `pluck` was the critical different I was looking for!